# Primefaces Mobile 0.9.4 does not work with Primefaces 4

Tags: jsf, mobile, primefaces

I have a web mobile application running on JBoss 7.1.1 AS, Mojarra JSF 2.1, Primefaces 3.5 and Primefaces Mobile 0.9.4.

Primefaces 4 was released for community. I updated it and the application crashed when using p:dataList.

Anyone knows if primefaces 4 supports primefaces mobile 0.9.4?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace or error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported. Have a look at this blog  [(http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2894)](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2894) and scroll to the comment by srbala. Not sure when mobile 1 is coming out. I'm waiting for it.

Comment: The best thing to do to continue using primefaces mobile 0.9.4 (last version) is roll back to primefaces 3.5.